# Como encontrar arquivos no eclipse que não usam uma determinada expressão?

Tags: eclipse

Existe uma forma de encontrar no "Search" do eclipse todos os arquivos que não contenham uma determina expressão?

Por exemplo: Eu gostaria de encontrar todos os arquivos dos projetos daquele Workspace que nao tenha a expressao "class".

Existe uma forma de fazer isso?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Sim!
No Eclipse, vá em **Search > File**. Lá, existe um campo chamado **"File name patterns"**. Nele você especifica todas as extensões que você deseja que apareçam no resultado da pesquisa.

**Veja o exemplo:**
[Imagem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOuSZ.png)

Selecionei todas as extensões através do botão **"Select All"**, e depois desmarquei a extensão que eu queria exibir nos resultados, que no meu caso foi o **.java**.

Também é possível informar outras extensões (ou até nomes de arquivos) para filtrar, no campo abaixo do botão de selecionar todos.

Answer (score -3):

Sim, é possível realizar essa busca utilizando a funcionalidade de "Pesquisa de Texto" do Eclipse. Para isso, siga os seguintes passos:

Abra o Eclipse e selecione o menu "Editar > Pesquisar > Texto". Isso abrirá a janela "Pesquisa de Texto".

Na caixa de texto "Contém o texto", digite a expressão que você deseja procurar. Por exemplo, para encontrar todos os arquivos que não contenham a expressão "class", você pode digitar "!class".

Na caixa de seleção "Em", selecione a opção "Arquivos de Projeto" para buscar somente nos projetos do seu Workspace.

Clique no botão "Pesquisar" para iniciar a pesquisa.

Os resultados da pesquisa serão exibidos na janela "Resultados da Pesquisa", onde você pode navegar pelos arquivos encontrados e abri-los para visualizar o conteúdo.

Observação: A funcionalidade de "Pesquisa de Texto" do Eclipse permite a utilização de vários operadores de busca, incluindo o operador "!" para negar uma determinada expressão. Para obter mais informações sobre esses operadores, consulte a documentação do Eclipse.